# problem with linking ressources with play feature delivery android app

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to use play feature delivery for an android app for splitting an app with more than 400 Mb size.

I didn't manage to link the file "videonamexyz.mp4" from the module "feature_video"
The absolute path in the module "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\namexyz\feature_videos\src\main\res\raw\videonamexyz.mp4"

The absolute path in the base "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\namexyz\app\src\main\res\raw"

the problematic part is

I want to use the following code propose by "https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery"

```
val uri = Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
                .authority(context.getPackageName()) // Look up the resources in the application with its splits loaded
                .appendPath(resources.getResourceTypeName(resId))
                .appendPath(String.format("%s:%s",
                  resources.getResourcePackageName(resId), // Look up the dynamic resource in the split namespace.
                  resources.getResourceEntryName(resId)
                  ))
                .build()
```

but I didn't manage to initialize "ResId" but the code wait for an int not to stringname of the file
I try that code " val resId = resources.getIdentifier("videonamexyz", "raw",  packageName)" but it doesn't seem to work.

the complete kotlin code of the activity is:

```
package com.namexyz.namexyz

import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer
import androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManagerFactory
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallRequest

class videonamexyz2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var player: ExoPlayer? = null
    private lateinit var splitInstallManager: SplitInstallManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.videonamexyz)

        splitInstallManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(this)
        val moduleName = "feature_videos" // Le nom de votre module de fonctionnalités dynamiques

        if (splitInstallManager.installedModules.contains(moduleName)) {
            // Le module est déjà installé, initialiser le lecteur directement
            initializePlayer()
        } else {
            // Le module n'est pas installé, demander son installation
            val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
                .addModule(moduleName)
                .build()

            splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    // Le module a été installé avec succès, initialiser le lecteur
                    initializePlayer()
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    // Échec de l'installation du module, gérer l'erreur
                }
        }
    }

    private fun initializePlayer() {
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build().also { exoPlayer ->
            val playerView: PlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view)
            playerView.player = exoPlayer

            val videoResId = resources.getIdentifier("videonamexyz", "raw", packageName)
          //  val uri = if (videoResId != 0) Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/$videoResId") else Uri.EMPTY
         //   val uri = if (videoResId != 0) Uri.parse("android.resource://${this.packageName}/${R.raw.videonamexyz}" else Uri.EMPTY
           // val videoFileName = "videonamexyz.mp4"
          // val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/")
          //  val filePath = "C:/Users/gilou/AndroidStudioProjects/namexyz/feature_videos/src/main/res/raw/videonamexyz.mp4"
          //  val file = File(filePath)
          //  val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
           // val videoFileName = "videonamexyz.mp4"
         //   val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/feature_videos/$videoFileName")

            //val videoFileName = "videonamexyz.mp4"
            //val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(videoFileName, "raw", packageName)

            //val resourceId = feature_video.R.raw.videonamexyz
            //val featurePackageName = "votre.package.nom.feature_video" // Remplacez par le nom du package de votre module de fonctionnalité
            // val resourceId = featurePackageName.R.raw.videonamexyz

          //  val resId = "videonamexyz.mp4"

           // val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$featurePackageName/$resourceId")



            //val uri = Uri.Builder()
              //  .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
               // .authority(this.packageName) // Utilisez packageName pour obtenir le nom du package de l'application
               // .appendPath("raw") // Spécifiez le dossier des ressources brutes
               // .appendPath("videonamexyz") // Nom du fichier sans extension
               // .build()


             val resId = resources.getIdentifier("videonamexyz", "raw",  packageName)


            val uri = Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
                .authority(this.getPackageName()) // Look up the resources in the application with its splits loaded
                .appendPath(resources.getResourceTypeName(resId))
                .appendPath(String.format("%s:%s",
                    resources.getResourcePackageName(resId), // Look up the dynamic resource in the split namespace.
                    resources.getResourceEntryName(resId)
                ))
                .build()




            val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
            exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            exoPlayer.prepare()
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            initializePlayer()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N || player == null)) {
            initializePlayer()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            releasePlayer()
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            releasePlayer()
        }
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        player?.let {
            it.release()
            player = null
        }
    }
}
```

the linking doesn't work, I want the linking works with play feature delivery module

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers